ERROR: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.malformed array literal
I have Postgres SQL function defined like below. It has a part where it runs a select query and has to store it in v_combination_exists variable. But it gives error in select statement.
ERROR:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.malformed array literal: "Check_ID1" 

ERROR:  malformed array literal: "Check_ID1"
SQL state: 22P02
Detail: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
Context: PL/pgSQL function abc.check_ids(character varying[]) line 19 at SQL statement

Function definition:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION abc.check_ids(
    id_values character varying[])
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    v_combination_exists character varying[];
BEGIN
...
                select id_value from abc.tableABC -- <-line 19
                    where id_value = ANY(id_values)
                INTO v_combination_exists;
    
            IF v_combination_exists exists THEN
                RAISE EXCEPTION 'The combination of provided fields already exists : %s', v_combination_exists ;
            END IF;
END;
$BODY$;

The way I am calling this function:
select  abc.check_id(id_values := ARRAY['Check_ID1','Check_ID2']);

Can someone please help in resolving the error?

Hi - that’s not a valid SELECT statement in your function

@NickW- Updated the select query. Had one filter added to check the working of query for other columns. But gives same error.

If you want to use named argument notation, the syntax is select  abc.check_id(id_values => ARRAY['Check_ID1','Check_ID2']); https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html or just use positional select  abc.check_id(ARRAY['Check_ID1','Check_ID2']);

Anyway, why are you denormalizing your database and then messing with functions to fix it up? Use a properly normalized join table of ABC_value (id_ABC, id_value)

The problem is that you are trying to assign a text value to a text array (assuming that id_value is text/character varying). This should work - allocate the duplicated values into an array and check if it is empty.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION abc.check_ids(id_values text[])
RETURNS void LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' COST 100 VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    v_combination_exists text[];
BEGIN
...
  select array_agg(id_value) from abc.tableABC
  where id_value = ANY(id_values)
  INTO v_combination_exists;
    
  IF array_length(v_combination_exists, 1) > 0 THEN
     RAISE EXCEPTION 'The combination of provided fields already exists: %s', v_combination_exists ;
  END IF;
END;
$BODY$;

Unless you need to allocate and use the list of duplicated values but only need to check if any of them already exists then it would be simpler:
if exists (select from abc.tableABC where id_value = ANY(id_values)) then
  RAISE EXCEPTION 'Some of the provided fields already exist: %s', id_values;
end if;

